# VS Code: activate (.)venv, automatically

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

After spending 5-6 hours trying to figure it out on my own , turning to the community for help.

I have been using VS Code for a couple years with Python on a Mac Mini (100+ projects).
Now migrated to a Mac Studio.

The behaviour I have on my old Mac (set up a couple years ago), is that upon opening a python script in VS Code and running it in the VS Code terminal, it automatically activates the venv (`/.venv` or `/venv` depending on project) and initiates by printing:

```
source /Users/n1c/PROJECT/.venv/bin/activate
```

(or `source /Users/n1c/PROJECT/venv/bin/activate` depending on project)

On my new Mac, I am unable to replicate this much needed behaviour.

Furthermore, even if I manually activate (`source venv/bin/activate`), it still runs with the global interpreter instead of the venv interpreter, eg

```
(venv) n1c@yyy test2 % /usr/bin/python3 /Users/n1c/PROJECT/test2.py
hello
```

Same behaviour across many projects tested.

How do I get VS Code to use the venv, and automatically activate on each run?

Notes:

- all projects have been fetched from Github to my new Mac OR just copy/pasted (including invisible files)
- VS Code Settings Sync is on, ie mirrored settings with old Mac
- in settings.json I have:

`{ "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true, "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true, }`

- I have also tried (for troubleshooting purposes) in .vscode/settings.json:
  `{ "python.pythonPath": "/Users/n1c/PROJECT/.venv/bin/python" }`
  to no avail

Comment: Have you investigated a specific `.venv/bin/activate` script to see what it should be doing and verified that that's what's happening? Looking at one myself, I see that `VIRTUAL_ENV` is set to the appropriate dir, exported, and appended to the front of `PATH`, which is also exported. Verifying these variables would be a first step.

You might also check if you have any aliases set on your new machine that might conflict. For example, if you have aliased `python`, the alias will take precedence.

Comment: Also, your point that manually running `activate` exhibits the same problem seems key. You might ignore the VSCode part of the problem for now and focus just on why your activate scripts aren't doing their jobs.

Comment: I have looked at a `.venv/bin/activate` script but without knowledge it looks good.
I have also tried creating a brand new project with a new venv (`python3 -m venv .venv`) and the `activate` script is different (my old ones were created with `virtualenv`) BUT same result (ie `source .venv/bin/activate` shows `(.venv) n1c@yyy test3 % /usr/bin/python3 /Users/n1c/test3/test3.py` so interpreter used is still the global one.

Comment: And the environment? Per e.g. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/132628/460319), there is a well-specified order of priority for command resolution. Run `activate` and then `type python` (or `type python3` if using that explicitly) to determine if a command or alias is being run. If command, examine the path (`echo $PATH`) to make sure everything's as it should be, i.e. `.venv/bin` should be at the front, and `python3` should be in that dir. I don't have any special knowledge of `venv`, but these sanity checks should help you narrow down.